# Circuit Analysis: R3(Missing), Voltage(Missing)

Tags: voltage, resistors, homework, analysis

This is a very simple circuit but I cannot solve it as I'm very slow in circuit analysis. Hence, I'd like to ask if someone can show me how to solve this one. [image]

Comment: What are ET, Pi3 and IT in relationship with the circuit you drew?

Comment: Trust Engine - Hi, For apparent assignment / test / homework-type questions like this, we need to see your own work *first*. That is currently missing, so we don't know specifically where you are stuck & your question has been "[closed](/help/closed-questions)". However as explained in that link, it will be put into a queue to consider re-opening it, if you [edit] your question, add your own analysis & your best solution attempt so far (how far can you get?). Make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck. Also respond to the comment above, to avoid guesses about what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're given total current as 3A. You are also given V_R3 = 38V.
Since all the current passes through R3, then I_R3 = I_total = 3A. Then use V_R3 = I_total * R3 to solve for R3.
Once that is done, using the method of combining parallel resistors to reduce the 2 branches into a single resistor values. Then you should have a circuit with E and 3 resistors.
Now you use the equation V=IR again but this time solve for the voltages across the resistors you just reduced. Remember you know the total current crosses them and you know their resistance, so solve for the voltage across them.
Finally, using Kirchhoff's law, we know that the sum of voltages is 0, so E = V_Rbranch1 + V_R3 + VRbranch2.

There are other ways to do it.